# How to fill colors in plotly based on a particular condition on a live plot?

Tags: python, nlp, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created a live plot and want to color code the graph based on if the value is positive or negative. Right now it's showcasing the same color for both positive and negative values.

[Live sentiment plot``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QnPh.png)

```
    data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
            x=X,
            y=Y,
            name='Sentiment',
            mode= 'lines',
            yaxis='y2',                          
            fill="tozeroy",
            fillcolor = "#6897bb"                            
            )

    return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                                      yaxis2=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)], side='left', overlaying='y',title='sentiment'),
                                                      title='Live sentiment for: "{}"'.format(sentiment_term),
                                                      font={'color':app_colors['text']},
                                                      plot_bgcolor = app_colors['background'],
                                                      paper_bgcolor = app_colors['background'],
                                                      showlegend=False)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an array of colors for each bar to the trace data.

So above, you would add a new property to data called marker, and that has a color property you can use.

```
x:..,
y:..,
marker:{
    color: [red,green,red,red...]
}
```

You can find the docs for customizing bar color here:

[PLotlyJS docs](https://plotly.com/javascript/bar-charts/#customizing-individual-bar-colors)

Answer (score 0):

Add `color_continuous_scale` argument:

```
color_continuous_scale=[(min(Y), "red"), (0, "red"),(0, "green"), (max(Y), "green"))
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to implement his in the above code? I tried adding this to my function but the graph stopped displaying all data?